# How do I change the z-index of a canvas element for DC.JS plot?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, dc.js

I'm using a canvas element in DC.JS and whenever I render background color (or anything else for that matter) the canvas disappears.

[image: Canvas plot without background styling]
[image: Canvas plot with background styling]

It seems this is likely due to a [z-index rendering](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/5d984c840e168aede1a4338d086d9f376118e885/src/charts/scatter-plot.js#L150) in the respective D3 element.

Any suggestions on how to remedy this?

Here's a [working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-54aw9n?file=style.css) to show the issue

P.S.

I've tried adding the following to no avail

```
eventScatterChart.select('canvas').style('z-index', 2000);
```

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. You have an` svg` element that draw the axes, and the canvas element that is the scatterplot. If you want to add a background color to can try to add a `rect` svg element before the `canvas` element.
z-index doesn't work in svg, the order is due the order you draw elements

Comment: Exactly what @vila said. You can use [`d3.selection.raise()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_raise) and `.lower()` to change the order of the drawn SVG elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like when the canvas scatter plot was implemented, the author had trouble because the canvas element is added after the svg element, which by default puts it forward in the z order — but the svg element needs to be in front in order for brushing to work.

Then the maintainer (I) did not catch this while reviewing the patch for merge, and did not suggest a better mechanism to achieve the goal, since it seemed to work.

You are on the right track with

```
eventScatterChart.select('canvas').style('z-index', 2000);
```

It's just that this needs to run after every render and redraw, and you also have to account for the svg layer in order for the brush to work:

```
  eventScatterChart.on('pretransition', chart => {
    chart.select('svg').style('z-index', 1);
    chart.select('canvas').style('z-index', 0)
  })
```

Here is a [working fork of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-mye5p9?file=EventScatter.tsx).

BTW, the folks talking about SVG z-index are completely correct, but this is not an SVG problem, since it has to do with the canvas and svg *HTML elements* inside the chart div, not any SVG elements.

I filed an issue [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1786). Thanks for raising this!

Comment: you the man! that's solved my issue, thanks! @Gordon

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add a background color to the scatterplot, you can try to add a `rect` svg element before the canvas element.

`z-index` doesn't work in SVG because [the order is due to the order you draw elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Getting_Started).

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but it is clear that @joshp is asking for a way to set the z index, and the reference to the CSS property is just a stab in the dark. Will remove if you edit your question with the useful information you provided in your comment. :)